# Jquery advice and a decision

Tags: jquery

This is code

```
$('input:radio[name=game]').click(function () {
    $('input[type=button].a').removeClass('activ-now', true);
});
```

First i have `input:radio[name=game] == 7/8/9` . Now i need do change the code to work like this

- from 7 to 8 (**ok**)
- from 7 to 9 (**ok**)
- from 8 to 9 (**ok**)
- from 8 to 7 (clear all)
- from 9 to 8 (clear all)
- from 9 to 7 (clear all)

So when Up its ok, when Down do clear

***clear all** = *`$('input[type=button].a').removeClass('activ-now', true);`*

here is all [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/v35RZ/)

Thanks

Comment: So...what seems to be the problem?

Comment: `input:radio[name=game] == 7/8/9 ` means what ? clarify in question itself properly. Also tell `from 7 to 8 (ok)` means what ?

Comment: See more information on the **here is all code**

Comment: please be specific what you exactly mean...

Comment: What does it mean _from 7 to 8_ ???? did you even read your own question ?

Comment: I need change the code to work, like i want.

Comment: please try answer the comments. your question is VERY unclear.

Comment: _So when Up its ok, when Down do clear_ ?? what is UP and what is DOWN ?

Comment: I show u whats i mean Up and Down (When + its Up) When - its down

Comment: You question is not clear what exactly the problem?

Comment: From what I understand those numbers are the Games. So if the user is on ex 8 and goes back to 7 it should clear the selected items. Simply put if the user advances to the next game the selected values should be kept, if he goes back it should reset.

Comment: @Spokey That is, I just do not know much English and did not know how to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option

```
$('input:radio[name=game]:checked').addClass('game-on');
$('input:radio[name=game]').click(function () {
    if(this.value < $('.game-on')[0].value)
        $('input[type=button].a').removeClass('activ-now', true);

    $('input:radio[name=game]').removeClass('game-on');
    $(this).addClass('game-on');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. stay with your option

Comment: One more qestion: Another way, if user play like on Game 9, and he change her mind, and wanna play now in Game 8, if user un-select one of activ-now buttons (and now its correct 8), where he click to Game 8 it will check count of selected, and if its = to game, it dosn't clear all. Understand me friend?

Answer (score 1):

I updated Fiddle check it

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v35RZ/12/)

```
var Previous1=$(this).attr('id').split('game')[1];
    if(Previous<=Previous1)
    {      
    }
    else
    {
    $('input[type=button].a').removeClass('activ-now', true);
    }
  Previous=Previous1;
```

Comment: Empty body of `if` looks weird

Comment: Just make it `>=` and you'll get rid if the empty body

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question in the right way. Anyway my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/v35RZ/13/) is here

I just added one variable `prevGame` that is used to make comparison

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prevGame;
```

and updated your radio button click event handler

```
  //When change game number, clear table numbers
    $('input:radio[name=game]').click(function () {
        var currentGame = parseInt($('input:radio[name=game]:checked').val());

        if (prevGame > currentGame) {
            $('input[type=button].a').removeClass('activ-now', true);
        }
        prevGame = currentGame;
    });
```